# Why doesn't the FParsec example run?

Tags: f#, fparsec

So I'm running the following code from the FParsec sample, but it doesn't seem to want to run.

```
namespace Test
open FParsec.CharParsers
module Stuff =
  let main = run pfloat "1.25E3"
  let str s = pstring s
  let floatBetweenBrackets = str "[" >>. pfloat .>> str "]"
```

The problem is the last line - I get this error:

```
Error   1   Expecting a type supporting the operator '>>.' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function. C:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Solution2\ConsoleApplication1\load.fs    6   42  Formatting
```

The code is from here:

```
http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#parsing-a-float-between-brackets
```

If it matters, the version of F# I'm running is:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.30110.0
```

Comment: I think `(>>.)` is defined in the `FParsec.Primitives` module, so you'll need to open that for the code to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>>.` is defined in `FParsec.Primitives`, so you need to open that as well. Alternatively, you can just open `FParsec`, [since](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#preliminaries)

> Opening the FParsec namespace also automatically opens the Primitives, CharParsers and Error modules.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35827709/2710074) explains why the error you're seeing is what it is.